# Preimage of a regular value : proving that the tangent plane is given by the kernel of the differential

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

In the book "Topology from the differential viewpoint" from John Milnor, we have the following theorem,

> Let $f: M \rightarrow N$ a smooth map between smooth manifolds of dimensions respectively dim($M$) = $m$ and dim($N$) = $n$.
> Let $y \in N$ a regular value of $f$.

> Then $Z := f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is a submanifold of dimension dim($M$) - dim($N$) and its tangent space $\forall p \in Z$ is given by,

> $$
>     T_p Z = \text{ker}(df_p: T_pM \rightarrow T_yN)
>   $$

I have trouble proving the second part of the theorem with the tangent space. Here's my attempt :

We know that $Z \subset M$ and $f: M \rightarrow N$.

We define the inclusion map:
$$
  i: Z \hookrightarrow{} N
$$

Then,
$$
f \circ i = F_{|_{Z}}
$$

We wanna show that $T_pZ \subset \ker(df_p: T_xM \rightarrow T_yN)$.
So, we know that,

$$
T_pZ := im(d(f_{|_Z})_p: T_pZ \rightarrow T_yN)
$$

Then,
$$
d(f_{|_Z})_p = d(f \circ i)_p = df_p \circ di_p : T_pZ \hookrightarrow T_pM \rightarrow T_yN
$$

Then,
$$
im(d(f_{|_Z})_p) = im(df_p \circ di_p) = T_yN \subset T_y\{y\} = im\{0\}
$$

So we have,
$$
T_pZ \subset im\{0\}
$$

Then I'm stuck here. How could I finish the proof ?

Comment: $im(df_p\circ di_p)=T_yN$ is not correct, nor is $T_yN\subset T_y\{y\}$. You're missing something there.